# Laravel database seeding from old tables

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How to populate new tables from data in old database tables using laravel?Both database have diffrent structure. Is it possible using Laravel seeding?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [multiple database connections](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections) in laravel to connect to both databases.

*config/database.php*

```
return [
    'connections' => [
        'old_db' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_OLD'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_OLD'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_OLD'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_OLD'),
        ],
        'new_db' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then in your seed file you can connect to your old database and loop through those items and insert them in your new database

*UserTableSeeder.php*

```
$users = DB::connection('old_db')->table('users')->get();

foreach($users as $user){
    DB::connection('new_db')->table('users')->insert([
        'name' => $user->username, //different fieldnames
        'email' => $user->emailaddress, //different fieldnames
    ]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were You and I needed **FAST** **one time** solution, I would:

Get data from old table using DB facade:

```
 $rows = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Structure my foreach something, which works in database seeder and echo it:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo("DB::table('table')->insert(array(
    'name' => '$row->name',
    'email' => '$row->email'
  ));
  <br />");
}
```

Copy&paste it into database seeder and run it **OR** structure statemens below to work directly in MySQL and run it in MySQL. It looks stupid, but very fast and works.

Code lines above aren't tested, written from memory.